No page numbering on certain pages
It seems like I have a problem at my page numbering. I used tikz to format the style of my sections and I made a new command for page numbering, also with tikz. The table of contents shows the page number correct, but each section shows page number in the footer just once.
When I run my code somewhere is an overlaping code that don't show my \Footer command on certain pages. Basicly I don't understand why on certain pages I don't get the output.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[tmargin=2cm,rmargin=2.8cm,lmargin=2.3cm,bmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Format section titles
\titleformat{\section}[display] 
{\bfseries\color{col1}}
{
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \fill[black, rounded corners=10] (0,0.9)--(-1.4,0)--(0,-0.8)--cycle;
        \fill[,rounded corners=10,col1!80,xshift=-0.5mm,yshift=-1mm](0,0.9)--(-1.4,0)--(0,-0.8)--cycle;
        \path[fill=black, draw=black!10, thick, xshift=-0.5mm, yshift=-0.5mm] (0,0) circle(0.5cm);
        \path[fill=white,draw=black!10,thick](0,0)circle(0.5cm)node[color=black](num){\thesection};
        \node[color=black,minimum height=2cm,minimum width=15cm,text width=10cm,align=left] (tit)at([xshift=7cm]num)[align=left,scale=1.2]{#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}{-25pt}{\bfseries\large}  % Add this line to include a horizontal line

\pagestyle{fancy} % Use fancyhdr package for headers and footers
\fancyhf{} % Clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot[C]{} % Clear center footer (remove the page number)

% Ensure that all pages use the empty style
\renewcommand{\thepage}{} % Remove page numbering
\pagenumbering{gobble} % Completely suppress page numbers

% FOOTER COMMAND %
\newcommand\Footer{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        % Check if the current page number is odd or even
        \ifodd\thepage
        % Odd page (right side)
        \node[anchor=south east, inner sep=20pt, outer sep=10pt] at (current page.south east) {
            \colorbox{col1}{\parbox[0.5cm][0.5cm][c]{2.5cm}{\centering\textcolor{white}{{\sffamily\bfseries\thepage}}}} % Right footer for odd page
        };
        \else
        % Even page (left side)
        \node[anchor=south west, inner sep=20pt, outer sep=10pt] at (current page.south west) {
            \colorbox{col1}{\parbox[0.5cm][0.5cm][c]{2.5cm}{\centering\textcolor{white}{{\sffamily\bfseries\thepage}}}} % Left footer for even page
        };
        \fi
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

%define new colors for our pagestyle%
\definecolor{col1}{RGB}{243,111,36}
\definecolor{col2}{RGB}{0,182,187}
\definecolor{col3}{RGB}{240,225,225}
\definecolor{col4}{RGB}{221,10,138}
\definecolor{col5}{RGB}{0,182,189}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{
    \clearpage % Start TOC on a new page without forcing an odd page
    \thispagestyle{empty} % No page number on TOC page
    \clearpage % Ensure the next content starts on a new page
}

%define style for table of contents
\titlecontents{chapter}[3.8pc]
{\addvspace{30pt}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
        \draw[fill=col1,draw=col1] (-100,-.11) rectangle (-0.1,.6);%
        \pgftext[left,x=-3.5cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Large\sc\bfseries Capitolul\ \thecontentslabel};%
    \end{tikzpicture}\color{col1}\large\sc\bfseries}%
{}
{}
{\;\titlerule\;\large\sc\bfseries Pagina \thecontentspage
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=col1!25,draw=col1!20] (2pt,0) rectangle (4,0.1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\titlecontents{section}[2.4pc]
    {\addvspace{1pt}}
    {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2.4pc}}
    {}
    {\hfill\small \thecontentspage}
    []
\titlecontents{subsection}[4.5pc] 
    {\addvspace{1pt}}
    {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2.4pc}}
    {}
    {\hfill\small \thecontentspage}
    []
\makeatletter

\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
    \chapter*{%
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
            \pgftext[right,x=25cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Huge\sc\bfseries \contentsname};%
            \draw[fill=col2,draw=col2] (10,-.75) rectangle (40,1);%
            \pgftext[right,x=15cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Huge\sc\bfseries \contentsname};%
    \end{tikzpicture}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
    \pagestyle{empty} % Hide default page numbers
    \frontmatter %non arabic numbers for pages

    %TABLE OF CONTENTS
    \tableofcontents

    \mainmatter   %arabic numbers to pages

    %FIRST PART
    \part{Recapitularea  materiei din clasele IX-X}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    

    %FIRST CHAPTER OF THE BOOK
    \chapter{Operații cu numere reale}
    \thispagestyle{empty} 
    
    \section{section1}
     \Footer
    \lipsum[10-50]
    \section{section2}
    \Footer
    \lipsum[10-30]

    \chapter{Functii}
    \Footer
    \thispagestyle{empty} % Suppress page number on this page
    
\end{document}


I would recommend to question it in its own community in tex.stackexchange. Did you try to set the Left\Right footer location: \fancyfoot[L]{On the left of the footer on all pages: \thepage} more details. it seems you don't see the output for in your code via \Footer bcz you are not addressing the page number like \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

You only use \Footer once on the first page of the chapter, so the page number is only printed once on the first page of the chapter.

i used \ Footer on sections as well but it makes just one page... basicly just the page that have a section tittle.

with the fancyfoot i did not know how to customize it with tikz for the same output i have. And in the command i used \thepage for odd and even pages. But since my section have 2-3 pages does not show the page number, just once
